# Select all nodes

Tags: c#, xml

I want to obtain all elements in the xml file.

I'm getting only the first element.

```
XmlDocument XDoc = new XmlDocument();
            XDoc.Load("d://avi.xml");        
            XmlNodeList XList = XDoc.SelectNodes("//level1");
            foreach (XmlNode XNode in XList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("the current node is - {0}", XNode.Name);
            }
```

The xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<level1>
    <level2>
        <level3>header3</level3>
            <level4>another</level4>
        <level31>header31</level31>
    </level2>
    <level2>
        <level3>nnn</level3>
        <level31>nnnnn</level31>
    </level2>
</level1>
<!--test test-->
```

Comment: So are you saying that there is more than one `<level1>` node and you would like to retreive them all?

Comment: no, thats the complete xml file i use, i want to get all the childs of the "level1" also, all the elements in the xml

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about trying:

```
XmlNodeList XList = XDoc.SelectNodes("//*");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string nodeSet = @"//* | //*/@*"; //gets both elements & attributes
XmlNodeList allNodes = XDoc.SelectNodes(@nodeSet);
```